# bigdelim does not respect arraystretch

Tags: tables, line-spacing, scaling, vertical

I use bigdelim to create a curly brace to the right of table columns. This works so far. However, when I set arraystretch to a value other than one, the vertical extent of the curly brace does not follow vertical scaling of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}


{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}%
  \begin{tabulary}{.9\textwidth}{LLL}
    \hline
    A & \rdelim\}{4}{3mm} & \multirow{4}{*}{X} \\
    B &                           &       \\
    C &                           &       \\
    D &                           &      \\
    E &                           &    Y \\     
    \hline
  \end{tabulary}
}

Curly brace too long with arraystretch \textless{} 1

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}%
  \begin{tabulary}{.9\textwidth}{LLL}
    \hline
    A & \rdelim\}{4}{3mm} & \multirow{4}{*}{X} \\
    B &                           &       \\
    C &                           &       \\
    D &                           &      \\
    E &                           &    Y \\     
    \hline
  \end{tabulary}
}

\end{document}
```

Here is what I obtain:

[image: Document generated]

How can I fix this problem? I need to have a smaller line spacing in the table for space reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While one can try to increase the row height of the 1st row by adding a `\strut` after the `A`, perhaps the easier approach is to insert a small blank line after the `\hline`, done here with `\hline\\[-9pt]` in the 2nd example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}


{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}%
  \begin{tabulary}{.9\textwidth}{LLL}
    \hline\\[-12pt]
    A & \rdelim\}{4}{3mm} & \multirow{4}{*}{X} \\
    B &                           &       \\
    C &                           &       \\
    D &                           &      \\
    E &                           &    Y \\     
    \hline
  \end{tabulary}
}

Curly brace too long with arraystretch \textless{} 1

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}%
  \begin{tabulary}{.9\textwidth}{LLL}
    \hline\\[-9pt]
    A & \rdelim\}{4}{3mm} & \multirow{4}{*}{X} \\
    B &                           &       \\
    C &                           &       \\
    D &                           &      \\
    E &                           &    Y \\     
    \hline
  \end{tabulary}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work on my system. I wonder whether there is a way to get rdelim to calculate the proper line height, considering arraystretch. Alternatively, is there another way to adjust the row height?

Comment: @user52366 You could try `\extrarowheight=3pt`

Comment: A negative extrarowheight has the same effect: the rows are shifted together with the curly brace staying the same size.

Comment: @user52366 The fact that your installation behaves this way, but not mine, is perhaps an indicator that some of your packages are out of date.  You should check to see that your package database is up to date.

Comment: It seems to have been a bug with my installation. On an updated system (kubuntu 17.10 instead of the 14.04) things work as expected. I accept this answer for pointing that out.

Comment: @user52366 Thank you.  Glad to hear the problem was resolved, even if one year out!

Answer (score 0):

I get the desired scaling using the spacing environment instead of arraystretch:

```
\begin{spacing}{.8}
   \begin{tabulary}{.9\textwidth}{LLL}
     \hline
     A & \rdelim\}{4}{3mm} & \multirow{4}{*}{X} \\
     B &                           &       \\
     C &                           &       \\
     D &                           &      \\
     E &                           &    Y \\     
     \hline
   \end{tabulary}
 \end{spacing}
```